# Complex Number Logarithm Paradox

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms, paradoxes

I think I may have stumbled upon a paradox today:

$$\ln(1) = 0$$
$$\ln(1) = \ln(-1^{2}) = 2\ln(-1)$$
$$\ln(-1) = \ln(e^{\pi i}) = \pi i$$
$$2\pi i = 0 \rightarrow i = 0$$

I can't seem to find the error with my logic. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: ln(-1) is not uniquely defined

Comment: [Basically what was said in another comment.] The logarithm is multivalued for domains containing more than positive real numbers.

Comment: You can see the "paradox"/fallacy even more clearly with: $\ln(-1)=\ln(e^{\pi i})=\pi i$ and $\ln(-1)=\ln(e^{-\pi i})=-\pi i$; or even $0=\ln(1)=\ln(e^{2\pi i})=2\pi i$.

Comment: The error is in the last step: $2\pi i=0 \to \pi=0$ is correct.

Comment: @vadim123 how is that correct

Comment: @rash, it is just as correct as the OP's reasoning, and meant to humorously illustrate the flaw.